# How do i access camera library on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using swift to develop a very simple iPhone app, where you can take a photo and save it to parse.

I'm wondering where can i find the documentation to access the camera library, because the only thing that I have found is swift documentation.

Any advice on how to tackle this, would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` is the object you'll implement. Apple's docs have a toggle for swift/objective-c at the top of the page.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a UIImagePickerController. [Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/) the official Apple documentation.

1. Make sure your view controller conforms to the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
   ```
2. Check if the user's device has a camera (a lot of people forget to do this).

   ```
   if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) { 
       // if the user's device has a camera, set the source type to camera
       picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
       // present the picker view controller
       self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
3. Implement the delegate methods

   ```
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
       // dismiss the picker controller
       picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
       // retrieve the image
       var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
   }

   func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {
       // user cancelled
   }
   ```